# Concat IQueryable collections in one db request

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I use entity framework.I need concat two collections.For example:

```
IQueryable<SomeType> collection1 = context.Entiies.Where(predicate);
IQueryable<SomeType> collection2 = context.Entiies.Where(otherPredicate);

var result = collection1.concat(collection2).toList(); //1
var result = collection1.union(collection2).toList; //2
```

Both 1 and 2 variant will do **2** requests in database,because these methods need IEnumerable as parameter.So,the question is can I concat two Iqueryble collections with one database call

Comment: why don't you use two predicates in same query?

Comment: @Selman22,this only example,to simply problem

Comment: Have you _verified_ that there are multiple DB requests or just _assuming_ there will be based on the extension method signatures?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are [`Concat()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb351755(v=vs.90).aspx) and [`Union()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb156049(v=vs.90).aspx) extension methods for `IQueryable<T>` in addition to `IEnumerable<T>`.  You can use them on queryable objects.  `Union()` maps to the SQL `UNION` operation and `Concat()` maps to `UNION ALL`.

As long as you don't convert the `IQueryable<T>` objects to `IEnumerable<T>` (either explicitly or implicitly) then you can just use these methods and they will be evaluated in the database if possible.

Further reading:

- [MSDN documentation for the `Queryable` class in .NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.queryable(v=vs.110).aspx).  This documents all of the extension methods that can potentially be evaluated in the database instead of in the CLR.

---

In glancing through the documentation I glossed over the detail that the extension methods declared on `Queryable` accept `IQueryable<T>` as the first parameter, but `IEnumerable<T>` as the second.  As D Stanley points out, these methods will test if the argument is an `IQueryable<T>` and if so will attempt to resolve the operation using the relevant query engine.

Comment: @cosset Each operation has an extension method for `IEnumerable<T>` *and also* one for `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: @cdhowie - not exactly - `Queryable.Concat` will examine the `IEnumerable` being passed in and use the underlying query expression _if it is an `IQueryable`_. There aren't separate overloads.

Comment: @DStanley I see what OP was saying now.  Thanks for reminding me of that; I've included that explanation in my answer.

Comment: @cdhowie In my case this throws a `The nested query is not supported. Operation1='UnionAll' Operation2='MultiStreamNest` exception. I am trying to implement a composite filter with logical **OR** operator. Meaning users can chain: *contains*: <value> **OR** *contains*: <secondValue>.

Comment: @Alex I'd suggest opening a new question with the details of your problem. Without more information (a code snippet and details of the Linq-to-SQL engine in use) it's not possible to assist.

Comment: @cdhowie Thanks, I believe I understand now. **EF** *allows* concatenation of two queries, but *throws* if those queries contain sub-queries on navigation properties. In such case, as far as I understand there is no option, but to *execute* the query, containing sub-queries, eg `ToList`